# Verify method call with a handle argument on an OCMockito mock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, tdd, ocmockito, ochamcrest

I have an OCMockito mock of a class *QuestionBuilder* with the method *questionsFromJSON:error:*. This method accepts a handle *(NSError **)error* as an argument. How do I verify the method was called?

I’ve tried:

```
[verify(builder) questionsFromJSON:@"Fake JSON"
                             error:nil];
```

and:

```
NSError *err;
[verify(builder) questionsFromJSON:@"Fake JSON"
                             error:&err];
```

Both issue the error:

> testQuestionJSONIsPassedToQuestionBuilder
>   (QuestionCreationTests) failed:
>   *** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:questionsFromJSON:error:] called!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OCMockito supports this yet; when I do it using given instead of verify, i get a weird error when the code under test calls the method with the ** argument. If possible you may have to modify your method signature to not take in an NSError** (if you have control over that code).